# Error image loading in Fabric.js (canvas.loadFromJSON)

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to load a previously saved database of the canvas. I get an error "error loadinghttp://flysite.byethost31.com/wp-content/plugins/coderisimo_diagram_constructor/user_images/rqtJkb.jpg" , But only in chrome. In firefox everything is working fine. The picture that the script can not load available. Link correctly. Thank you.

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.di-links', function () {
var id = jQuery(this).attr('di-id');
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url,
    data: {'diagram_id': id, 'action': 'get_user_diagram'}
}).done(function (json) {
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    canvas.loadFromJSON(data.diagram, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));//ERROR
    jQuery('#diagram-title').val(data.title);
    id_loaded_diagram = id;

});
```

video  - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19954007/WHY.mp4

Help!!!

Comment: Instead of adding more information in comments, edit your post. Also, I can't get your image to load to see what it says, can you put it on a more reliable host?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I couldn't see a URL that the webapp is running on - is it the same domain as where the image gets loaded?  I'm wondering if you are running into a cross-origin issue.  http vs https, www vs non-www, www vs othersubdomain, etc. can cause issues here.  If there is any variagion in the protocol, subdomain, and domain then it's most likely cross-origin issues.  If not, not so sure....

Comment: @PromInc  yes! site [link](http://flysite.byethost31.com) and pictue loads from  [link](http://flysite.byethost31.com/wp-content/plugins/coderisimo_diagram_constructor/user_images/rqtJkb.jpg).And what  about  : in FireFox all ok ? I was at an impasse.